# Tailwind custom themes and @apply classes

Tags: css, vuejs3, tailwind-css

i am running into some problems compiling my CSS. I create 3 custom classes in my  index.css file and also use @apply for some longer classes.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@font-face {
    font-family: "Spartan";
    src: url('/fonts/static/Spartan-Bold.ttf') format("truetype");
}

@layer base {
    :root {
        --main: "#3a4764";
        --keypad: "#232c43";
        --screen: "#182034";
        --key-blue: "#637097";
        --key-shadow-blue: "#404e72";
        --key-red: "#d03f2f";
        --key-shadow-red: "#93261a";
        --key: "#eae3dc";
        --key-shadow: "#b4a597";
        --text-dark: "#444b5a";
        --text-white: "#ffffff";
    }

    .themeLight {
        --main: "#e6e6e6";
        --keypad: "#d1cccc";
        --screen: "#ededed";
        --key-blue: "#377f86";
        --key-shadow-blue: "#1b5f65";
        --key-red: "#ca5502";
        --key-shadow-red: "#893901";
        --key: "#e5e4e1";
        --key-shadow: "#a69d91";
        --text-dark: "#35352c";
        --text-white: "#ffffff";
    }

    .themeRetro {
        --main: "#160628";
        --keypad: "#1d0934";
        --screen: "#1d0934";
        --key-blue: "#58077d";
        --key-shadow-blue: "#bc15f4";
        --key-red: "#00e0d1";
        --key-shadow-red: "#6cf9f2";
        --key: "#341c4f";
        --key-shadow: "#871c9c";
        --text-light: "#ffe53d";
        --text-dark: "#1b2428";
        --text-white: "#ffffff";
    }
}
```

where in my css file do i write the classes which use @apply? My classes with @apply all use the color variables from my custom themes like so:

```
.key {
        @apply w-1/5 h-1/6 flex justify-center items-center rounded-md border-b-4 pt-2 font-bold text-3xl;
    }

    .keyColor1 {
        @apply border-skin-key-shadow bg-skin-key text-text_dark;
    }

    .keyColor2 {
        @apply border-skin-key-shadow-blue bg-skin-key-blue text-white text-xl;
    }

    .keyColor3 {
        @apply border-skin-key-shadow-red bg-skin-key-red text-white;
    }

    .toggle {
        @apply bg-skin-key-red;
    }
```

My tailwind config file:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: {
        skin: {
          main: "var(--main)",
          keypad: "var(--keypad)",
          screen: "var(--screen)",
          'key-blue': "var(--key-blue)",
          'key-shadow-blue': "var(--key-shadow-blue)",
          'key-red': "var(--key-red)",
          'key-shadow-red': "var(--key-shadow-red)",
          key: "var(--key)",
          'key-shadow': "var(--key-shadow)",
          'text-dark': "var(--text-dark)",
          'text-white': "var(--text-white)",
        }
      }
    },
  },
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Figured out the problem i had some extra parantheses around the hex color codes in

```
:root {
        --main: "#3a4764";
        --keypad: "#232c43";
        --screen: "#182034";
        --key-blue: "#637097";
        --key-shadow-blue: "#404e72";
        --key-red: "#d03f2f";
        --key-shadow-red: "#93261a";
        --key: "#eae3dc";
        --key-shadow: "#b4a597";
        --text-dark: "#444b5a";
        --text-white: "#ffffff";
    }
```

--key-shadow: "#b4a597"; should be --key-shadow: #b4a597;.